# React to incoming SMS/MMS while respecting the default SMS/MMS database

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms, intentfilter, contentobserver

Is there any way to react to changes to the SMS/MMS ContentProvider (even when app is inactive.)

I want to act on message data as it comes, but also as the default Messenger app uses it.

If I use a BroadcastReceiver with a Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION IntentFilter, I only get the raw message BEFORE the SMS ContentProvider gets it.

And I can't use a ContentObserver because I want to be able to react to messages when my app isn't active.

Comment: You're mostly right, except that the message received in the BroadcastReceiver doesn't have the thread_id field. I assume that the default messenger app creates that field.

Comment: Yeah I thought of the Service + ContentObserver but that just sounds like a huge pain battery/memory-wise. Saving the number and body is actually not a terrible idea, but it becomes a problem if someone likes to start conversations with "hey." Adding the timestamp might make that work.

Comment: I actually solved it by using a NotificationListenerService. If a notification from the default messenger app pops up, then I query the database.

Comment: Although if I want to also do stuff with sent SMS, then the Service + ContentProvider might be the best option. Do you think that's how Pushbullet does it?